# Send Mail not working in web Mail Account of Cpanel

Tags: php, email

Hello i have problem in sending a mail in cpanel's webmail Account.
I tried this code and it's working perfectly i tried it with gmail account and another cpanel's account. 
Example : I changed the $to field with abc@gmail.com & info@domainname2.com (Another Cpanel account) & both of them working perfectly.

And it's not working with same Domain Name. My code is in domainname1 and i'm sending mail to the same domain.

```
$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$subject = "foo";
$body = "foo";

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

if(@mail($to, $subject, $body, implode("\r\n", $headers)))
{
  echo "Mail Sent Successfully";
}else{
  echo "Mail Not Sent";
}
```

Comment: You're suppressing errors in your `mail()` function. Maybe these errors might give you a clue.

Comment: @Henders. i tried with error_reporting(E_ALL); but it give me no error. and i tried mail function with 3 email address . 1 is of gmail , 1 is of another cpanel account & both of them working so i'm confused.

Comment: The `@` symbol before the `mail()` function will suppress all errors and not log them. Remove the `@` symbol to have those errors logged/displayed on screen.

Comment: @Henders actually its a ajax call. so, i tried without @ and i tested it same issue occurs again.
if you want than i can edit my question with console log of mozilla.

Comment: @Henders. can you please tell me where is the email setting in Cpanel? 
there is one solution on web that replace Exim logs with one command where is exact exim log in cpanel ? i have full access of this cpanel

Comment: To confirm, you removed the `@` _and_ put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` in your script, then ran it and there was still no error there..?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113506/discussion-between-bhavinv-and-henders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with MX Records. 
MX records are pointing to google Account's Email address. So, now i set MX records of my domains & this problem hase been solved. 
thanks for your help @Henders.